# CakePHP - Views and controllers for managing HABTM models?

Tags: php, cakephp, view, has-and-belongs-to-many, controllers

Is there somewhere that I can get a default set up for a GUI (views and controllers) for managing an HABTM relationship between two models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really specific so here is a generic answer:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake

Check this URL it will show you how to build basic code using the bake shell for your app that already will allow you CRUD actions and browse your records.

If your database schema follows the conventions CakePHP will detect that and generate the correct forms and model associations, also for HABTM.